# Error install Shorebird using cURL command

Tags: command-line-interface, shorebird

I tried to install Shorebird on my Mac, but I terminated the task by mistake, the command line was

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shorebirdtech/install/main/install.sh -sSf | bash
```

Now I tried the same command, but gives me this error:

**Error: Existing Shorebird installation detected. Use --force to overwrite.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution using this command

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shorebirdtech/install/main/install.sh -sSf | bash -s -- --force
```